# Declaring Local Object in C++

Tags: c++

One of the Question on C++ FAQ discusses correct way to declare local object within a function: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fn-decl-vs-obj-instantiation.html

Given example from FAQ:

```
class Bar { 
public: 
  Bar();
};

class Foo {
public:
  Foo(Bar const& b);
  void blah();
};

void yourCode()
{
  Foo x(Bar());  // error     
}
```

In VS2012, error is `Foo x(Bar (__cdecl *)(void))': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)`

Could someone explain me why this this declaration gives an error ?(C++ FAQ explanation is too vague).
`Foo` and `Bar` are both visible within body of `yourCode()`, and `Foo x(Bar());` is a way I would declare an object of type `Foo`.

Comment: Google "most vexing parse" and you will get the answer.

Comment: Some help: [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: Not providing this as an answer as I'm sure its a dupe, As mentioned its called "most vexing parse" ... Fix is either add an extra set of brackets `Foo x((Bar()));` or extract the `Bar` instance as a variable `Bar bar; Foo x(bar);`.

Comment: @C.R. Could you give this as answer ? I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @newprint: Other people have more detailed answers. You could accept those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this C++'s the most vexing parse, you can do:

```
Foo x((Bar()));
```

or

```
Foo x = Bar();
```

The details are reviewed in the very parashift link you provided in your question.
Note though, the second example will break if the `Foo` copy constructor is made `explicit`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a `const` consistency problem.  The constructor for `Foo` wants a `const` `Bar` which `Bar()` isn't.  Try:

```
const Bar b = Bar();
Foo x = Foo(b);
```

Comment: @zneak, Then it takes an unnamed `Bar` as the parameter. The easiest fix is `Foo x{Bar{}};` imo, but it's C++11.

Comment: Oh crap, you're right.

Comment: @zneak, Tricky C++ is tricky :p Anyway, I'll leave that since it hasn't been mentioned.